# Update visibility of an element on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

HTML:

```
       <div class ="container">
            <div class="ui top attached segment"> 
                <div class="item">
                    <p>Post here</p>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="extra">
                        <div class="ui right floated button">
                            <i class="download icon"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui right floated button quickstats">
                            <i class="pie chart icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui label">
                    <i class="time icon"></i>
                    timeStamp
                </div>
                </br>
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached block secondary clearing segment hidden">
                <p>bottom</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.quickstats').on('click', function(){
    var statBar = $(this).closest('.extra').closest('.item').closest('.segment').closest('container').find('.stats');
    if (statBar.hasClass('hidden')){
        statBar.removeClass('hidden')
        statBar.addClass('visible');
    } else {
        statBar.removeClass('visible')
        statBar.addClass('hidden');   
    }
})
```

When I click the button with the class quickstats, I want the div at the bottom with the paragraph element that says "bottom" to show. On the next click, I want to it to become hidden again.

I will have multiple of the HTML elements on a screen at once so I cannot directly select the element but have to use a combination of parent, child and sibling relationships. I have tried the current method for the jquery but have had no success.

On click of the div with class quickstats, how can I select the div with the hidden class and then toggle visibility back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all you forgot to add **stats** class, see I added it below

```
<div class="stats ui bottom attached block secondary clearing segment hidden">
    <p>bottom</p>
</div>
```

2nd you don't need to chain to get to the top element with **container** class... you can do like this below... **closest** function will find its way to the element you are looking for...

```
var statBar = $(this).closest('.container').find( ".stats" );
```

So basically just these 2 small changes... add **stats** class to the element you want to hide and show and get rid of chaining...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your entire `if` statement, you can just use `statBar.toggle();` which will make it hidden if it's visible or visible it it's hidden.

If you want this with the toggle slide animation, you can use `statBar.slideToggle();` which is always cooler.

To sum it up in your own code:

```
$('.quickstats').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.extra').closest('.item').closest('.segment').closest('container').find('.stats');
    statBar.toggle();
});
```

**Important**: Don't forget to change the `hidden` class in your CSS - since JQuery works on the `display` property, **not** `visibility`, so set the element as `display:none` if you want it hidden at first. In general, try using `display` and not `visibility`.

[Read more about `toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).